# Fetch each FrameLayout div elements inside the RecyclerView

Tags: android, appium-android

```
List<WebElement> ulElement = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView[@index='0']/give_the_class_name_of_framelayout"));
int sz = ulElement.size();
System.out.println(sz);
```

From the code above I am getting the size of the elements, but I also need to print the element names.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, hope it will helps

```
List<WebElement> ulElement = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView[@index='0']/give_the_class_name_of_framelayout"));
int sz = ulElement.size();
System.out.println(sz);

for(WebElement e: ulElement){
    System.out.print(e.getText()+"\n");
}
```

Have a look the output result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply Sir.. but im not getting the element names

Comment: So, it should work, it's working fine for me, please have a look the screenshot.

Comment: Thanks Sir, there are 10 elements... but im getting size is 7 and getting output only 7 elements.. Remaining 3 elements are not getting counted and printed. Im assuming not scrolling down that is the reason I'm getting only display elements... please sir help me to achieve this

Comment: Actually in Android only able to read the view part in the screen, you have to manage it by scroll function.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to do that